# CoreText framework in iOS 5 using Base SDK 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode5, core-text

When building my iPad app, I am using a Base SDK of Latest iOS (iOS 7.1) and a Deployment Target of 5.0.

When trying to run the app on an iPad 1 running iOS 5.1, it crashes on launch with the following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _kCTFontDescriptorMatchingError
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/C5593F35-B25C-415F-95A1-45CD617804ED/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
```

in /var/mobile/Applications/C5593F35-B25C-415F-95A1-45CD617804ED/MyApp.app/MyApp

I tried removing and adding the CoreText.framework again, and made sure that the Location is set to Relative to SDK.

Is there another setting that needs to be updated in Xcode 5.1 to be able to run on iOS 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kCTFontDescriptorMatchingError` constant is only available from iOS 6 onwards.